# Trying to lookup a value in PowerBI from a table that contains many different lookup types

Tags: powerbi

We have a data source that contains lookup values, however the master list of all the lookup values are stored within one table - for all lookup lists. This table contains fields for the lookup name, the lookup value, and the lookup description. The lookup name thus will have multiple rows, one for each possible value and its corresponding description.

While we know how to make a relationship between two tables, we do not know how to handle this situation where a single lookup table contains many different lookup lists. We need to match a value, filtering only on rows where the lookup name is a certain text, that is, the name of the specific lookup we are using.

We figure maybe a calculated column will work, but are reasonably new to Power BI and are struggling on the syntax.

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to import in the Lookup table multiple times, each time filtering it down to only one set of lookups. Name the table the same as the filtered LookupName.
You'd end up with one table for each LookupName.